# jQuery droppable draggable remove DnD more than one

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I posted earlier an issue with DnD that is solved now but during testing I saw that there was an error in the other code: the "remove" action.
I am sure it is totally logical, and that I am missing the logical explanation for it but I can't find any answers on the internet (yet) nor in the books where DnD is hardly touched.

The issue is that when a droppable has been targetted with more than one (>1) droppable, It will result in a return of ALL earlier dropped when doing the REMOVE on it.

See for your self : http://jsfiddle.net/BCnyU/

Follow these steps:

> 1) "drag 2" on "drop 3"
>   2) "drag 1" on "drop 4"
>   3) "drag 4" on "drop 5"
>       Nothing special, just to get them out of our way.
>   Now do this:
>   4) "drag 3" on "drop 1"
>   5) click "undo" of the "drag 3"
>   6) "drag 5" on "drop 1"
>   7) "drag 3" on "drop 2"

What happend is that we have had TWO (2) drop events on the "drop 1".
When you click now on the "undo" of "drag 5", you might expect that "drag 5" only will return.
But NO NO... "drag 5" and "drag 3" will appear !!!

Who can explain me that, and give also a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time an element is dragged onto a drop area, you are attaching a click handler to that drop area.  These click handlers are never removed so they remain on the area in addition to the new one being added.  The more you add and remove elements, the more click handlers are bound.

The easiest way to fix this without changing your code would be to change `click` to `one`.  `one` allows you to attach a handler which will only execute once.

http://jsfiddle.net/BCnyU/101/

```
      .one("click",function(){
        $(ui.draggable).show();
        $(this).css("color","black");
        $(this).text(oldvalue);
        $(this).droppable({disabled:false});
        $(this).removeClass('OK NOK');
        var numItems = $('.OK').length;
        $('.counter').html('Correct: '+numItems +'/5'); 
      });
```

Another option would be to add the click handler to the "UNDO" anchor tag, rather than the entire drop area.  Then when the "UNDO" anchor is removed the handler would be removed as well.

Comment: Perfect. And thanks for the technical feedback.
I will implement this code and will try to get the second one also working because that one is more "clean".
I guess I have to dive into the "bind" command, not ?